# if jCheckBox.isSelected() to display a new jTextArea (NetBeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, jtextarea, jcheckbox

I have a jCheckBox that, if the user checks it, creates a jTextArea under it, pushing everything and, if diselected, it disappears, pulling everything back.
Something like this, but in Java.: https://youtu.be/gcNa0uqxytg?si=0u9VLzOvHX25c1E4&t=321

I already tried something like this, but nothing happens when I check/uncheck it.:

```
if(jCheckBox.isSelected()) {
jTextArea.setVisible(true);
} else {
jTextArea.setVisible(false);
}
```

Tried this too, but it causes error.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ul1q.png)

Comment: Java Swing is not CSS/HTML.  One thing you can do is display a `JCheckBox` and a `JTextField`.  if the check box is selected, enable the text field, otherwise, disable the text field.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: What is the event  that your calling that code in?

Comment: @Lutz It is a form that user can check.
If checked, the user can increment with more details about the service in the jTextArea. Otherwise, let he can let unchecked.
I have only a "jCheckBoxActionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error image you show your problem is not in the code you put up but rather in `evt.getStateChange()`. Also you don't strictly need that if statement and could just change the whole method to a single line:

```
private void JCheckboxActionPerformed(...) {
  txtField.setVisible(jCheckbox1.isSelected())
}
```

If that does not work then the problem might actually be in the layout and not the text field itself.

You should add the text field visible to your form and ones your happy how it looks you add

```
txtField.setVisible(false);
```

to the end of the constructor of the form.